# Bootstrap installation error

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to install bootstrap to use it in flask application but it gives me that

[image: error]

My pip is up to date, any help?

I am using PyCharm professional edition and this are the details of the error log after following the flask_bootstrap tutorial

[image]

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't support installing via pip.  I assume you mean this [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), whose install methods only include `npm` and as a Rubygem.

Comment: when I run "sudo pip install flask-bootstrap" it gives me that :
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /home/salwa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->Flask>=0.8->flask-bootstrap)

Comment: when I tried npm install bootstrap it gives me that error :
/home/salwa/PycharmProjects/Catalogproject_SalwaAhmed
├── bootstrap@4.1.3 
├── jquery@3.3.1 
├── popper@1.0.1 
└── popper.js@1.14.4 
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /rijs.resdir/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4

Comment: npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/salwa/PycharmProjects/Catalogproject_SalwaAhmed/package.json'

Comment: Those are only warnings.

Comment: I am using that import in my app : from flask-bootstrap import bootstrap
and it gives me that error !! ImportError: cannot import name bootstrap
I have installed bootstrap using npm

Comment: If flask’s import doesn’t work correctly, I would look at the Flask documentation, and submit a bug upstream if needed.  I did notice from your image that bootstrap may not need to be capitalized

Comment: I am using pycharm and it suggest installing bootstrap and it appears error in the event log that the command "pip install bootstrap" and it gives the error referred before !!! so I am wondering why pycharm use the pip to install it and why it does not work !

Comment: The correct line is `from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap`. Please read the documentation carefully: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html

Comment: Also, don’t try to fib readers in your question. Your `pip` is not up to date, which may create a new issue later.  10.01 != 18.1, which is in the image you posted

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

1. Remove Everything you've done if you have the Professional Edition,
2. Read the [Creating Flask Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-flask-project.html) help file
3. Add the [bootstrap extension](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html)

No need to use `npm` unless you're using the Community or Educational version.  If you've already followed the steps I outlined above, please update your question with your PyCharm version, and your error log.